# Show a message, when an application is deploying to JBoss

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jboss, jboss7.x

How can I show a message to alert users, when I deploy an application over JBoss AS 7.1.1?

Technologies that I am using:

- Shiro 1.2.3
- Mojarra 2.1.7
- PrimeFaces 5.1
- JDK 1.7
- JBoss 7.1.1

Comment: What is that "*message*" about?

Comment: To tell users that the application is down while jboss finishes to deploy the application. The message could be: "We are updating the web site right now, please wait some seconds."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put a barebones webserver in front of JBoss AS, acting as a proxy. Usually, [Apache HTTPD](http://httpd.apache.org/) is being used for this (you know, that server which PHP folks overgeneralize as "Apache"). Then, configure that maintenance screen as its HTTP 404/503 error page.

The serveradmin should know how to do this. This is at least not JSF (nor programming) related. Such an Apache HTTPD thing has more benefits, by the way, such as more powerful caching and URL rewriting as compared to JBoss AS (we're also using it at ZEEF, in front of WildFly).

Comment: If its a high traffic site [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/) offers better performance than Apache.